# deleting convox apps which are linked to resources

Tags: infrastructure, convox

I'm getting a weird error from convox when I go to delete a resource:

```
$ convox apps delete my-app
Deleting my-app... ERROR: app is linked to syslog-1234 resource
```

Weirdly, when I investigate that resource, I see nothing.

```
$ convox resources info syslog-1234 --app my-app
ERROR: ValidationError: Resource ResourceSyslog1234 does not exist for stack convox-rack-my-app
    status code: 400, request id: 9f364cc8-ec82-45fd-aca1-015c4a2395e3
```

It's like the resource which is blocking my delete action doesn't exist. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You have to unlink the resource before delete the app, like:

```
convox rack resources unlink syslog-1234 --app=my-app --rack=your-rack-name --wait
```

Comment: this is correct, however newer versions of convox do not support the --wait flag (it waits by default now)